{{% if user.is_authenticated %}} is not working properly it always shows the authenticated block and not else block
.................urls.py..........
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include
from user import views as user_view
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('register/', user_view.register, name = 'user-register'),
    path('profile/', user_view.profile, name = 'user-profile'),
    path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'user/login.html'),name='user-login'),
    path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'user/logout.html'),name='user-logout' ),
    
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

...........views.py........
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('user-login')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/register.html',context)


def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'user/profile.html')

.........nav.html........
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-info bg-info">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="{% url 'dashboard-index' %}">NTPC Inventory</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'dashboard-index' %}">Dashboard <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="profile.html">Admin Profile <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'user-logout' %}">Logout</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            
           <!-- problem is not solved as is.authenticated is not working as it show logout and admin profile for the same still finding out the solution -->
          {% else  %} 
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'user-register' %}">Register <span
                            class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-white" href="{% url 'user-login' %}">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</nav> 

I have tried importing different libraries but still unable to find the solution, whenever I clear the cookies of chrome it works for that single load of page only once i reload, it again comes to the same .
It shows the authenticated block at the nav as
Admin profile logout
but doesn't show register login option.

you are crossing HTML <div>s with the logical template blocks. That may not be the source of your error, but makes for it to be almost impossible to follow, incorrect HTML, that would render just because all browsers got hardned against such incorrect markup. (In this case you'd get extraneous closing </div> tags without the corresponding opening tags.)

User.is_authenticated()  isn’t False then. You invoked authenticate() or login() before. You can try clearing Session Storage.

Clarify if the user is logged in or not when the issue occurs. Provide more context on the authentication setup.

Your Jinja syntax is need a little bit changing. If you wanna check a user is authenticated or not in the django template, you need to do this as below :
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <a href="{% url 'user-logout' %}" class="appointment-btn scrollto">Logout</a>
          <a href="{% url 'user-profile' %}" class="appointment-btn scrollto">Profile-{{ user.username }}</a>
{% else %}
          <a href="{% url 'user-login' %}" class="appointment-btn scrollto">Sign in / Sign up</a>
{% endif %}

You forget the request in the template. Also, you can check a user is authenticated or not in the views like this :
def profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'user/profile.html', {'user':request.user})
    else:
        return redirect('user-login')

Your urls.py has two paths with empty path.check it out :
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include
from user import views as user_view
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # see this one and,
    path('', include('dashboard.urls')),

    path('register/', user_view.register, name = 'user-register'),
    path('profile/', user_view.profile, name = 'user-profile'),
    
    # see this one 
    path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'user/login.html'),name='user-login'),

    path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'user/logout.html'),name='user-logout' ),
    
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

I suggest to change one them to something else, for example :
rom django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include
from user import views as user_view
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('register/', user_view.register, name = 'user-register'),
    path('profile/', user_view.profile, name = 'user-profile'),

    # I'v changed this to login path
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'user/login.html'),name='user-login'),
    path('logout/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'user/logout.html'),name='user-logout' ),
    
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


The default context processors add both request and user into the context, where user is request.user. So their template can be said to be correct (unless they added some other user object into the context from their view).

I have tried that request.user also before but it didn't work now as you suggested to I have tried that changes also in views but the problem remains same it didn't solved that issue. if request.user.is_authenticated is always true.

I think, I found your problem. check above again.

It didn't affected, the problem remains the same. In  login page  it shows the logout option and profile option instead of login and register.
